# Unit Testing using Moq fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am new to the unit testing world so please spare me. The goal of the question is to test a class as mentioned below:

```
public class Engine
{      
    #region Members
    private EnumDefinition.EngineRunningState runningState;
    private ComponentController componentController;
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Engine(ComponentController componentController)
    {
        this.componentController = componentController;

    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public EnumDefinition.EngineRunningState RunningState
    {
        get
        {
            return runningState;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (value != runningState)
            {
                componentController.EngineRunningStateChangedEvent += OnEngineRunningStateChange;               
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Start the Engine Request
    /// </summary>
    public void StartEngineRequest() 
    {
        // Check Engine Status
        if (runningState == EnumDefinition.EngineRunningState.Off)
        {
            componentController.SetEngineRequestToActive();
        }
        else if (runningState == EnumDefinition.EngineRunningState.Error)
        {
            logger.Trace("Engine Start Request Sent on a ENGINE ERROR!!!!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Trace("Engine Start Request, Engine is still ON");
        }

    }
    private void OnEngineRunningStateChange(object sender, EngineRunningStateArgs e)
    {
            runningState = e.runningStateofEngine;
    }
}
```

I want to test the public functions in Engine. Now I present my Test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class EngineTest
{       
    [Test]
    public void StartEngineRequestTest()
    {
        Mock<ComponentController> mockComponentController = new Mock<ComponentController>();
        Mock<EngineRunningStateArgs> mockEngineRunningStateArgs = 
            new Mock<EngineRunningStateArgs>(EnumDefinition.EngineRunningState.On);
        var engineTest = new Engine(mockComponentController.Object);
        mockComponentController.Raise(mock => mock.EngineRunningStateChangedEvent += null, mockEngineRunningStateArgs.Object);              
        engineTest.StartEngineRequest();
    }
}
```

mt test fails giving an error as mentioned below: 
`Result StackTrace: 
at Moq.Extensions.GetEvent[TMock](Action 1 eventExpression, TMock mock)
   at Moq.Mock 1.Raise(Action 1 eventExpression, EventArgs args)
   at AutoTugTest.EngineTest.StartEngineRequestTest() in C:\GatewayController\01 Working Copy\GatewayComputer\AutoTugTest\EngineTest.cs:line 23
Result Message: System.ArgumentException : Expression is not an event attach or detach, or the event is declared in a class but not marked virtual.`

I have no idea what is happening.
I just want to throw an event from `ComponentController` with event name as `EngineRunningStateChangedEvent` with an event argument. 
Please suggest.

Comment: is the event declared as `virtual`?

Comment: From https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/61 - _"Events are no different than everything else. They have to be virtual to be mockable."_

Comment: My events are not virtual, and why should they be virtual? What purpose does it serve. Do I have to make a fake event which is virtual. If so, what's the point of MOQ! @nozzleman

Comment: Every Member that you want to mock has to be virtual in order to be mockable for technical reasons (to be overridden dynamically by MOQ). alternatively, you can use an interface. But you do not need a face event, just mark the existing one as virtual

Comment: You should use interfaces more in your code

Answer (score 2):

Moq can only mock virtual members. It's good at mocking interfaces because there's no implementations, but if you want to mock a concrete class the members that you mock will need to be virtual. That lets Moq wrap the 'real' implementation with it's own.